What information is available to users with the “site analytics” privilege?
Apparently with the “site analytics” privilege a user can see two graphs that show a timeline of posts and votes.  Do these graphs simply show the number of posts/votes over time?
Can they view any other information?

Yes, that is the information shown. See the help page

Two graphs show a timeline of posts and votes. Date selectors across the top of the page control the range of dates displayed:

Site milestone dates are also provided and, if clicked, will change the start date of the graphs. Selecting the "Weekly" checkbox will change the data points to per week.
Data series can be toggled via checkboxes to the left of each chart:

Get a CSV copy of the displayed data suitable for offline analysis by clicking the "csv" link. Note that this data includes information on deleted posts.

